# Fail device in md RAID when ATA stops responding

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, io, raid6

I had created **five 1TB HDD partitions** (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdc1`, `/dev/sde1`, and `/dev/sdf1`) in a **RAID 6** array called `/dev/md0` using `mdadm` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr.

The command sudo `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` used to show all drives in *active sync*.

Then, for testing, I simulated long I/O blocking on `/dev/sdb` by running these commands while `/dev/sdb1` was still active in the array:

```
hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass deltik /dev/sdb
hdparm --user-master u --security-erase-enhanced deltik /dev/sdb
```

> #### *WARNING*
>
> *DON'T TRY THIS ON DATA YOU CARE ABOUT!*
>   
>   <sup><sub>I ended up corrupting 455681 inodes as a result of this ATA operation.  I admit my negligence.</sub></sup>

The ATA command for secure erase was expected to run for 188 minutes, blocking all other commands for at least that long.

**I expected `md` to drop the unresponsive drive like a proper RAID controller, but to my surprise, `/dev/md0` became blocked as well.**

`mdadm --detail /dev/md0` queries the blocked device, so it freezes and won't output.

Here's the layout from `/proc/mdstat` while I can't use `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`:

```
root@node51 [~]# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid6 sdf1[5] sda1[0] sdb1[4] sdc1[2] sde1[1]
      2929887744 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

I tried `mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdb1` to forcefully fail `/dev/sdb1`, but that was also blocked:

```
root@node51 [~]# ps aux | awk '{if($8~"D"||$8=="STAT"){print $0}}' 
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      3334  1.2  0.0  42564  1800 ?        D    03:21   3:37 parted -l
root      4957  0.0  0.0  13272   900 ?        D    06:19   0:00 mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdb1
root      5706  0.0  0.0  13388  1028 ?        D    06:19   0:00 mdadm --detail /dev/md0
root      7541  0.5  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jul19   6:12 [kworker/u16:2]
root     22420  0.0  0.0  11480   808 ?        D    07:48   0:00 lsblk
root     22796  0.0  0.0   4424   360 pts/13   D+   05:51   0:00 hdparm --user-master u --security-erase-enhanced deltik /dev/sdb
root     23312  0.0  0.0   4292   360 ?        D    05:51   0:00 hdparm -I /dev/sdb
root     23594  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        D    06:11   0:07 [kworker/u16:1]
root     25205  0.0  0.0  17980   556 ?        D    05:52   0:00 ls --color=auto
root     26008  0.0  0.0  13388  1032 pts/23   D+   06:32   0:00 mdadm --detail /dev/md0
dtkms    29271  0.0  0.2  58336 10412 ?        DN   05:55   0:00 python /usr/share/backintime/common/backintime.py --backup-job
root     32303  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    06:16   0:00 [kworker/u16:0]
```

---

**UPDATE (21 July 2015):** After I waited the full 188 minutes for the I/O block to be cleared, surprise turned to horror when I saw that `md` treated the completely blanked out `/dev/sdb` as if it were completely in tact.

I thought that `md` would have at least seen that parity was mismatched and then would have dropped `/dev/sdb1`.

Panicking, I ran `mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdb1` again, and since the I/O block had been lifted, the command completed quickly.

Filesystem corruption was already happening as input/output errors cropped up.  Still panicking, I did a lazy unmount of the data partition in the RAID array and a `reboot -nf` since I figured it couldn't get any worse.

After a nail-biting `e2fsck` on the partition, 455681 inodes made it into `lost+found`.

I've since reassembled the array, and the array itself looks fine now:

```
root@node51 [~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Feb 16 14:34:26 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 2929887744 (2794.16 GiB 3000.21 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976629248 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jul 21 00:00:30 2015
          State : active 
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : box51:0
           UUID : 6b8a654d:59deede9:c66bd472:0ceffc61
         Events : 643541

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       97        1      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       6       8       17        3      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       5       8      113        4      active sync   /dev/sdh1
```

It's still quite a shock to me that `md` doesn't have two lines of protection that I expected:

- Failing a device when it locks up
- Failing a device when the data it returns are garbage

---

#### Questions

1. Why doesn't `md` fail the unresponsive drive/partition?
2. Can I drop the drive/partition from the array while the drive is blocked?
3. Can a timeout be configured so that `md` automatically fails a drive that isn't responding to ATA commands?
4. Why does `md` continue to use a device with invalid data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Deltik](https://superuser.com/users/83694/deltik), you've misunderstood how Linux Software RAID (`md`) works.

`md` makes a virtual block device out of multiple devices or partitions and has no awareness of what data you are transferring to and from the virtual device.

**You hoped that it could do things that it wasn't designed to do.**

---

### Answers

#### 1. Why doesn't `md` fail the unresponsive drive/partition?

This is because `md` has no idea whether

- the drive is busy with I/O from something that `md` itself requested or
- the drive was blocked due to some external circumstance like the drive's own error recovery or in your case an ATA Secure Erase,

so `md` will wait to see what the drive returns.  The drive eventually didn't return any read or write errors.  If there was a read error, `md` would have automatically fixed it from parity, and if there was a write error, `md` would have failed the device (see the "Recovery" section of the [`md` man page](http://web.archive.org/web/20141119125349/http://linux.die.net/man/4/md)).

Since there was neither a read error nor a write error, `md` continued using the device after the kernel waited for it to respond.

#### 2. Can I drop the drive/partition from the array while the drive is blocked?

No.  The `/dev/md0` RAID device is blocked and can't be modified until the block is cleared.

You passed the `-f` or `--fail` flag to the `mdadm` "Manage" mode.

Here's a walkthrough of what that actually does:

[This is the source code of how that flag works](https://github.com/neilbrown/mdadm/blob/653299b6/Manage.c#L1566):

```
case 'f': /* set faulty */
    /* FIXME check current member */
    if ((sysfd >= 0 && write(sysfd, "faulty", 6) != 6) ||
        (sysfd < 0 && ioctl(fd, SET_DISK_FAULTY,
                rdev))) {
        if (errno == EBUSY)
            busy = 1;
        pr_err("set device faulty failed for %s:  %s\n",
            dv->devname, strerror(errno));
        if (sysfd >= 0)
            close(sysfd);
        goto abort;
    }
    if (sysfd >= 0)
        close(sysfd);
    sysfd = -1;
    count++;
    if (verbose >= 0)
        pr_err("set %s faulty in %s\n",
            dv->devname, devname);
    break;
```

Notice the call `write(sysfd, "faulty", 6)`.  `sysfd` is a variable set earlier in the file:

`sysfd = sysfs_open(fd2devnm(fd), dname, "block/dev");`

`sysfs_open()` is a function from [this file](https://github.com/neilbrown/mdadm/blob/5418499a/sysfs.c):

```
int sysfs_open(char *devnm, char *devname, char *attr)
{
    char fname[50];
    int fd;

    sprintf(fname, "/sys/block/%s/md/", devnm);
    if (devname) {
        strcat(fname, devname);
        strcat(fname, "/");
    }
    strcat(fname, attr);
    fd = open(fname, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0 && errno == EACCES)
        fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    return fd;
}
```

If you follow the functions, you'll find that `mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdb1` essentially does this:

```
echo "faulty" > /sys/block/md0/md/dev-sdb1/block/dev
```

This request will be waiting and won't go through immediately because `/dev/md0` is blocked.

#### 3. Can a timeout be configured so that `md` automatically fails a drive that isn't responding to ATA commands?

Yes.  In fact, [by default, the timeout is 30 seconds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/22e0d994/drivers/scsi/sd.h#L11):

```
root@node51 [~]# cat /sys/block/sdb/device/timeout
30
```

The problem with your assumption was that your drive was actually busy running an ATA command (for 188 minutes), so it wasn't timing out.

For details about this, see the [Linux kernel SCSI error handling documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/scsi/scsi_eh.txt).

#### 4. Why does `md` continue to use a device with invalid data?

When the ATA Secure Erase finished, the drive did not report any issues, like an aborted command, so `md` had no reason to suspect that there was an issue.

Furthermore, in your case of using partitions as the RAID devices instead of whole disks, the kernel's in-memory partition table wasn't informed that the partition on the wiped drive was gone, so `md` would continue to access your `/dev/sdb1` like nothing was wrong.

This is from the [`md` man page](http://web.archive.org/web/20141119125349/http://linux.die.net/man/4/md):

> ### Scrubbing and Mismatches
>
> As storage devices can develop bad blocks at any time it is valuable to regularly read all blocks on all devices in an array so as to catch such bad blocks early. This process is called *scrubbing*.
>
> md arrays can be scrubbed by writing either *check* or *repair* to the file *md/sync_action* in the *sysfs* directory for the device.
>
> Requesting a scrub will cause md to read every block on every device in the array, and check that the data is consistent. For RAID1 and RAID10, this means checking that the copies are identical. For RAID4, RAID5, RAID6 this means checking that the parity block is (or blocks are) correct.

We can infer from this that parity is not normally checked on every disk read.  (Besides, checking parity on every read would be very taxing on performance by increasing the transactions necessary just to complete a read and running the comparison of the parity to the data read.)

Under normal operation, `md` just assumes that the data it is reading are valid, leaving it vulnerable to [silent data corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_data_corruption).  In your case, you had an entire drive of silently corrupted data because you wiped the drive.

Your filesystem wasn't aware of the corruption.  You saw input/output errors at the filesystem level because the filesystem couldn't understand why it had bad data.

To avoid silent data corruption, first, **don't ever do what you did again**.  Second, consider using [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), a filesystem that focuses on data integrity and detects and corrects silent data corruption.