# mdadm RAID 6 drive failed over, then some of my data disappeared

Tags: linux, raid, data-recovery, software-raid

**Background**

For 7 years now I've had a personal file/media server running Fedora (initially 21, currently 30).  The main storage array comprises 3TB drives in an mdadm RAID6 (originally, RAID5).  Over the years, a few drives have died and been replaced; I've grown the array; etc.  Most recently, it was 6 drives + a hot spare in RAID6 (12TB usable space).  There had never been any issue with failover or rebuilding the array; everything just kept on chugging like you'd expect from a redundant RAID array.  But, unfortunately, due to the size of the array, I never had a backup and relied on the RAID for resilience.

**The Incident**

Until last week.  I was randomly browsing the server and noticed a ton of my files were no longer there.  (A bunch of other files were untouched, though, including some backups of my other computers, funny enough.)  Upon noticing that, I immediately checked `/proc/mdstat` and found that one of the drives had failed and the hot spare had been subbed in.  Great, I thought, there must have been some filesystem snafu while the failed drive was in its death throes.

I then unmounted the array before any more damage could be done, and then I physically removed the failed drive from the system (after confirming with `smartctl` that it's really dead).  And that was basically the last smart thing I did.  I ran `fsck` and it kept finding issues ("ref count 2, expected 1") and asking if I wanted it to fix it.  TL;DR, 48 hours later `fsck` had finished having its way with my array.  I re-mounted it and immediately ran `df`, which showed 5.8T used out of 11T (it used to be in the 9.5T used range).  Obviously I'm a bit upset about probably losing 4TB of data for, as far as I can tell, no reason, so I started researching options for data recovery.  However, since I don't have any other volume that's even close in size, I appeared to be SOL.  So I resigned myself to picking through `lost+found` and finding out what data had managed to survive.

**Current State**

The array is a healthy six-drive RAID6 (no more hot spare) with a 12TB ext4 filesystem which appears to be healthy (no issues mounting/unmounting, no more `dmesg` errors, `fsck` has no complaints).  Of the 5.8TB of data reportedly still present, roughly 500GB is as it was before and the remaining 5+TB is in `lost+found`.

**My Question**

Before I start actually going through these files and trying to put them back where they belong, is there anything else I can try to recover the 4TB of "missing" data?  (Is it possible that it's not really gone?)  Or am I just totally hosed because I ran `fsck` too hastily?

And does anyone have any "tricks" for handling the lost+found recovery?  Based on other posts I've read, such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177691/restore-from-lostfound, I'm expecting to basically use `file` in a script to segregate files by type and then if I'm lucky I'll be able to use baked-in metadata to help automate sorting most them.

Comment: Wow! This reads a lot like [what happened to me](https://superuser.com/q/942886/83694). My RAID damage was self-inflicted, but I also had no backups, so I had to sift through 455681 files in `lost+found`.

Comment: @Deltik :O  Yeah, sounds similar!  And to be clear, I'm not blaming `md` for anything that happened here.  (Also not the first time someone's told me to use ZFS.  If I end up with enough free space to form a second array in parallel, I'll take this "opportunity" to do that migration...)